# Select Multiple values from a previously selected dropdown value in Django form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement the steps given in this example (https://github.com/Sidon/djfkf/) to create a Django form that allows for multiple selection of values based on a previous selection. Essentially, I have two models, one for the organism and the other for targets. Each organism can have one or more targets. I would like to select an organism, and once I've selected the organism, a drop down menu appears having all its related targets. I used opt-groups but is not giving me what I desire. Could someone kindly assist. Am new to web programming. This is just but a part of the bigger task, which is to develop a bioinformatics app. Have a look at the code for this specific purpose.

```
### models ####
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible 
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import os
from os import path

@python_2_unicode_compatible  
class reference(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class target (models.Model):
    uploadtargetfs = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'targets/')
    target_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="") 
    reference_organism = models.ForeignKey(reference, default="")
    forward_file = models.FileField(upload_to=uploadtargetfs)
    reverse_file = models.FileField(upload_to=uploadtargetfs)

    def organism(self):
        return self.reference_organism.description



    def __str__(self):
        return self.target_name
        return self.reference_organism

##### forms ####
import json
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from django_select2.forms import (
    HeavySelect2MultipleWidget, HeavySelect2Widget,    ModelSelect2MultipleWidget,
ModelSelect2TagWidget, ModelSelect2Widget, Select2MultipleWidget,
Select2Widget
)

from .models import reference, target

class ReferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = reference
        fields = ('description', 'file',)

class RegTargetForm(forms.ModelForm):

    dvarieties = {}
    list_varieties = []
    for variety in target.objects.all():
        if variety.reference_organism.description in dvarieties:
            dvarieties[variety.reference_organism.description].append(variety.target_name)
        else:
            dvarieties[variety.reference_organism.description] =     [variety.target_name]
        list_varieties.append((variety.target_name,variety.target_name))
    references = [str(reference_organism) for reference_organism in reference.objects.all()]
    reference_select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(reference_organism, reference_organism) for reference_organism in references])
    variety_select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(list_varieties))


references = json.dumps(references)
varieties = json.dumps(dvarieties)

class Meta:
    model = target
    fields = ('reference_select', 'variety_select',)


#### views ####

import os
from os import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile, File
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from .models import reference, target
from .forms import ReferenceForm, RegTargetForm

def select_target(request):

    targets = target.objects.all()
    targets_ids = targets.values_list('id', flat=True) 
    targets_list = targets.values_list('id').values('reference_organism', 'target_name','forward_file', 'reverse_file')
    targets_queryset = targets.values('reference_organism', 'target_name','forward_file', 'reverse_file')

    if request.method == 'GET':
        variety_form = RegTargetForm(data=request.GET.getlist('target_choice'))

        if variety_form.is_valid():
            vdata = variety_form.cleaned_data.get
            variety_selected = target.objects.filter(target_name=vdata('variety_select'))
            var1 = target(reference_organism=variety_selected[0].id, target_name=vdata('target_name'))
            var1.save()
        else:
            return render(request, 'polymorph/select_target.html', {'variety_form':variety_form})
    else:
        variety_form = RegTargetForm()
    return render(request, 'polymorph/home.html', {'variety_form':variety_form})

#### urls ####

from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views
from .views import *


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^tutorial/$', views.tutorial, name='tutorial'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^get_reference/$', views.get_reference, name='get_reference'),
    url(r'^select_target/$', views.select_target, name='select_target'),   
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


#### select target html ####

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="select-style">
    <form action="", method="get">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ variety_form.as_p }}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Select"></p>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block js %}
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        //alert('funcionou')
        $('#id_variety_select').change(function() {populatetarget(this)});
        $('#id_reference_organism').addClass('reference_organism');
        varieties = {{ variety_form.varieties | safe }}
        references = {{ variety_form.references | safe }};
        populatereference();
        $('#id_reference_select').empty();
        $('#id_reference_select').append('<option value="" disabled selected>First select a reference organism</option>');

        function populatereference() {
            $('#id_reference_select').empty();
            $('#id_reference_select').append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select reference organism</option>');
            $.each(references, function(v) {
                $('#id_reference_select')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", references[v])
                .text(references[v]));
            });
        }
        function populatetarget(event) {
            reference = $("id_reference_select option:selected").text();
            $("id_variety_select").empty();
            $("id_variety_select").append('<option value="" disabled selected> Select variety</option>')
            for (let [v, vvarieties] of Object.entries(varieties)) {
                if (v == reference) {
                    //alert(v);
                    for (variety in vvarieties) {
                        $('#id_variety_select')
                            .append($("<option></option>")
                                .attr("value", vvarieties[variety])
                                .text(vvarieties[variety]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Kindly see the attached image displaying how I'd like it to appear

Comment: Please, edit your question, show your code and explicit your problem.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I made a summarized test with your models and everything worked fine.

Comment: @Sidon. Could you kindly share the summarized test? I modified the html file using javascript. The task at hand now is how do i fetch/get the value (i.e file) for the organism and its target(s) once a user has made the selection. Again, if a user opts to upload a target file, how do i connect that to the organism he has selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I have time to post your test.

### core/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Organism(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Target(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    organism = models.ForeignKey(Organism)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Register(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    organism = models.ForeignKey(Organism)
    target = models.ForeignKey(Target)
```

### core/forms.py

```
import json
from django import forms
from .models import Organism, Target, Register

class BioForm(forms.ModelForm):

    dtargets = {}
    list_targets = []
    for target in Target.objects.all():
        if target.organism.name in dtargets:
            dtargets[target.organism.name].append(target.name)
        else:
            dtargets[target.organism.name] = [target.name]
        list_targets.append((target.name, target.name))

    organisms = [str(organism) for organism in Organism.objects.all()]

    organism_select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=([(organism, organism) for organism in organisms]))
    target_select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(list_targets))

    organisms = json.dumps(organisms)
    targets = json.dumps(dtargets)

    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = ('organism_select', 'target_select', 'description',)
```

### core/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import BioForm
from .models import Organism, Target, Register

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BioForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # ... Save your data
            pass
        else:
            # Your implementation
            pass

    else:
        form = BioForm()
    return render(request, 'core/register.html', {'form': form})
```

### core/templates/core/register.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Registering organism/targets on the Register. <br />(Populate one drop down based on selection in another)</h1>
    <p>Change the contents of drop down Target based on the selection in dropdown Organism, using Django-forms + Javascritp</p>
    <div class="select-style">
        <form action="." method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <p><input type="submit" value="Register a organism/target"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
    {% include "js1.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

### core/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register')
]
```

### core/templates/js1.html

```
{% block js %}
    <script language="javascript">

        alert('Load script')

        $('#id_organism_select').change(function() {populateTarget(this)});
        $('#id_description').addClass('descriptions');

        targets = {{form.targets | safe }}
        organisms = {{ form.organisms | safe}};
        populateOrganism();
        $("#id_target_select").empty();
        $("#id_target_select").append('<option value="" disabled selected>First select a brand</option>');


        function populateOrganism() {
            $('#id_organism_select').empty();
            $("#id_organism_select").append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>');
            $.each(organisms, function(v) {
                $('#id_organism_select')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", organisms[v])
                    .text(organisms[v]));
            });
        }

        function populateTarget(event) {

            organism = $("#id_organism_select option:selected").text();
            $("#id_target_select").empty();
            $("#id_target_select").append('<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>');
            for (let [o, otargets] of Object.entries(targets)) {
                if (o == organism) {
                    for (target in otargets) {
                        $('#id_target_select')
                            .append($("<option></option>")
                                .attr("value", otargets[target])
                                .text(otargets[target]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

### Project files:

```
.
├── biotool
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── core
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── static
│   │   └── css
│   │       └── base.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── core
│   │   │   └── register.html
│   │   └── js1.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

### Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: thanks much for this. However, I get an error : django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: poly_target. I did perform another implementation using your approach and it works. The only problem is that am unable to select multiple targets. Again, I cannot able to access the data when i finally want to run the entire analysis.