# Django Multiple Choice Field Options depend on value of Drop-down Menu

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How to display one of several sets of Multiple Choice Field options based on the on value of currently selected in a drop-down menu?

Comment: Thanks for submitting your first question on SO. But please, check [ask] to see what type of question we expect here. You should try to search if your question hasn't been answered before (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604085/select-multiple-values-from-a-previously-selected-dropdown-value-in-django-form)) and you should try to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: @dirkgroten I wish everyone on stackoverflow would be as kind as you. 

Comment: @Ahtisham.  Amen to that!

Comment: I agree that it’s not always clear how to search for existing answers.  but... SOs system provides a bit of builtin help:  as you compose your **question**, keep an eye on the right side of the screen and you may see a list of related questions that the system is recognizing from your own question’s formulation.  i’ve sometimes hit jackpot and stopped my question formulation.